# function inside a for loop in javascript retrieves 2nd value rather than the first value

Tags: javascript, protractor

i got a json object array which has list of "USERS". I tried to Iterated thru the array using for loop which then calls another function whether the user

```
//Check for User if already existed or not
queryUserEmail = function(User){
    return emailQueryElement.sendKeys(User,protractor.Key.ENTER).then(function(){
        return usersListElement.all(by.css('.shortHand')).getText().then(function(text){
            if(text.toString().indexOf(User)!=-1){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false
            };
        });
    });
};  

this.createUser = function(userArray){
 for(var userI=0;userI<userArray.length;++userI){
        var UserEmail = userArray[userI].UserEmail;
        logger.info('UserEmail outside function::'+UserEmail);
        queryUserEmail(UserEmail).then(function(checkFlag){
            logger.info('UserEmail inside funtion::'+UserEmail);
        });
    };
};
```

and User array contains two users,when i tried to run the Function, for the first iteration outside function UserEmail has the array first user email, but inside the function the userEmail has the second user's email.

Am i missing something here?

Comment: This has already been answered, but let me clarify. .then() returns a promise, which is something that JavaScript will do alongside or after the other functions and code after it. Instead of doing it automatically, it's letting the for loop run again, then it's finally saying, "Oh, I just found time to actually run this function." By that time, the UserEmail has already been incremented again, so it's only going to run the checkFlag function with the new UserEmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an asynchronous/closure issue. If so, wrap the `queryUserEmail` function in a function closure (IIFE):

```
for ( var userI = 0; userI < userArray.length; ++userI ) {
    var UserEmail = userArray[userI].UserEmail;
    logger.info('UserEmail outside function::' + UserEmail);
    (function (uEmail) {
        queryUserEmail(uEmail).then(function(checkFlag){
            logger.info('UserEmail inside funtion::' + uEmail);
        });
    }(UserEmail))
};
```

By the time `then` (a property of `queryUserEmail`) fires, the `for` loop has completed and `UserEmail` is the last assigned user.